# Why is work done = resisting force * displacement?

Tags: thermodynamics, work, definition

Up until now, I have always seen the formula of work done as force * displacement and I thought that this force was applied force but recently in a thermodynamic text while reading about irreversible processes I encountered this formula ie.,

Work = resisting force * displacement

So, how come resisting force contributes in work done and not the applied force? Can someone plz explain this intutively with an example.

Comment: Work done by a constant force on an object ,is  that force times displacement of the object.

Comment: Please link to the source where you recently encountered this

Answer (score 1):

From my understanding, resisting force is a force that acts against an objects motion. For example, friction on a moving object.
Basically, resisting force is also an applied force, but we just need to take into consideration the direction that it is acting in.
So say we take the case of a block sliding on the ground moving towards the right. Friction acts towards the left against the motion and therefore displacement and is a resisting force here.
And it does work as it slows down the block, and this work can be quantified by force * displacement

Resisting force is just a more descriptive name for the force that is applied. Therefore it is not a fundamentally different formula. The direction of the force just opposes the displacement, and so the formula "resisting force * displacement" is the same as "applied force * displacement" as it is an applied force

Answer (score 0):

We can talk meaningfully about the work done **by** any particular force in an object's motion.  So, for example, if an elevator rises at constant velocity, the force applied by the cable does a certain amount of work on the elevator, while gravity also does a certain amount of work on it.  We can also talk meaningfully about the *net work* done on an object by all forces;  in this case, this would just be
$$
\text{net work} = (\text{work done by cable}) + (\text{work done by gravity}).
$$

In this particular case, the two forces are opposite in direction but have the same magnitude, so the amounts of work done by each of the two forces cancel out (one is positive, one is negative);  and so the net work is zero.  This is consistent with the work-energy theorem, which says that the net work done on an object is equal to its change in kinetic energy.

Comment: Exactly and this why the usual claim that the gas does *work* an amount of  $pdV$ cannot be right, because against *what* is the work done when it expends in a vacuum? Work can only be done if the transported quantity is moved from one potential (pressure, force) to another, say $(p_1-p_2)dV$. The $dV$ volumetric expansion must represent  the transport of matter not volume and that must then involve change in the chemical potential, see http://actachemscand.org/author.php?aid=12991, pp1226-1227